# access inherited class properties from base class

Tags: c#, oop, class, inheritance, radix

I have base class and two inherited classes, these two inherited classes also share the two properties. I would like to access these properties from base class. How to do that? Example below.

```
public abstract class ClientEngine
{
        public void SaveFile(string fileName);
        {
            //Not implemented, I get error here because I don't know how to access Inherited class properties
            if (FileStorage != null))
                File.WriteAllBytes(fileName, FileStorage);
        }
}

    public interface IEngineEntity
    {
        byte[] FileStorage { get; set; }
    }

public class MyEntity1 : ClientEngine, IEngineEntity
{

public string MyProperty1 {get; set;}
public string MyProperty2 {get; set;}

public byte[] FileStorage { get; set; }
}

public class MyEntity2 : ClientEngine, IEngineEntity
{

public string MyProperty3 {get; set;}
public string MyProperty4 {get; set;}

public byte[] FileStorage { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: You are looking for a thin metal ruler: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2003/11/03/a-parable.aspx Please consider the feedback you are receiving about your design and think carefully whether bending the concept of OO to your will is truly the right answer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you need to access a property from the base class, you are doing something wrong. Keep that in mind for your future designs.

You should declare `FileStorage` in the base class, since both inherited classes have it.

If you do not want to define `FileStorage`'s specific type (say, `byte[]`), you might want to define it as a more generic type, such as `IEnumerable<byte>`. Alternatively, you can declare `FileStorage` as an interface who provides whatever behavior you need to access from base class.

**Update**

A nice observation by @ghimireniraj: you should also try to derive ClientEngine from IEngineEntity.  One of the bottom lines for OO design is that if you replicate behavior in all inherited classes, it should be in the base class.

But, do you really want to access some code from base class? You shouldn't. But if you really need, you can always cast:

```
public abstract class ClientEngine
{
    public void SaveFile(string fileName);
    {
        byte[] fileStorage = null;
        if (this is MyEntity1)
        {
            MyEntity1 me1 = (MyEntity1)this;
            fileStorage = me1.FileStorage;
        }
        else if (this is MyEntity2)
        {
            MyEntity2 me2 = (MyEntity2)this;
            fileStorage = me2.FileStorage;
        }
        if (fileStorage != null))
            File.WriteAllBytes(fileName, fileStorage);
    }
}
```

Nasty right? But it should look dirty, because we are trying to break OO design.

**Update**

Another way is going by Marc Gravell's suggestion. Instead of casting to the types, cast to the interface. But all of this still smells bad to me: I firmly believe you can improve your design.

Comment: Or derive ClientEngine from IEngineEntity.

Comment: @ghimireniraj Good catch. One of the bottom lines for OO design: if you replicate behavior in all inherited classes, it should be in the base class.

Comment: I can't because MyEntity1 and MyEntity2 is serialized using protobuf-net and there is reason not to put FileStorage in base class but rather implement it as interface. I just not pasted the whole code. So back to question, how to access properties of Inherited classes from base class without changing logic.

Comment: @Tomas not sure I see the relationship between protobuf-net and this design decision. If you let me know what issue you are trying to avoid, I can probably advise...

Comment: @downvoter Please comment the downvote. Let's make this community more constructive.

Comment: @Adrian:  Then, Can you instead not derive MyEntity1 and MyEntity2 from ClientEngine, but rather have ClientEngine functions take an argument of type MyEntityBase which MyEntity1 and MyEntity2 derive from?

Answer (score 3):

The way to do that is to make it an abstract member in the base class, and override in the derived; the other approach you could use is to try casting `this` to `IEngineEntity` - if it succeeds, use it via the interface, i.e.

```
var engine = this as IEngineEntity;
if(engine == null) throw new InvalidOperationException(
   "All engine implementations must provide an IEngineEntity implementation");
var bytes = engine.FileStorage;
```

It does seem a little *unusual*, though, not to push this down to the base-class if it is a mandate of all subclasses. By pushing it to the base-class, you **cannot** forget to implement the missing member.

Comment: Yup. 1. abstract member in the base class to force a child to implement it; 2. virtual member in the base class for the optional override in a child; 3. an interface implemented by the child for the situation when not all children are supposed to have it.

Answer (score 1):

Another functional alternative:

```
var derivedType = Type.GetType(this.GetType().FullName);
var FileStorage = derivedType.GetProperty("FileStorage", BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.NonPublic).GetValue(this) as byte[];
if (FileStorage != null) 
{
    ...
}
```